# Python: Counting Occurrences of a Word From a txt file with Input

Tags: python, input

I am new to programming and I need help finding how many times the user input occurs inside of a txt file. The code I currently have is:

```
myfile = open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt")

count = 0
team = input("Enter in the team name that won the world series: ")
line = myfile.readline()

myfile.readline()

while team in line:
    count += 1

myfile.readline()

print("The", team, "won the world series", count, "times")



myfile.close()
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Enter in the team name that won the world series: New York Yankees
The New York Yankees won the world series 0 times
```

How would I get it to show many times a specific team won? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post a few lines of the text file?

Comment: if that team is in the line then you have yourself an infinite loop, you should probably use `lower()` or `upper()` on line and team so that the case matches

Comment: Related - [python read all lines in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949508/python-read-all-text-file-lines-in-loop#17949545)

Comment: Could you use `split()` on the line and then `count()` on the resulting list?

Comment: @ElliotRoberts no need to `split` before using `count()` as it works on strings

Comment: Count is a list method, no? Wouldn't the line be a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
team = input('Enter team name: ')
count = 0
with open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if team in line:
            count += 1

print('{} won the world series {} times'.format(team, count)
```

Go through line by line and check each line using `if` statements

Comment: This is a good solution if we assume the file has the whole team name on one line (like a list) and is not broken over a new line (like in a paragraph with some formatting restrictions).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have a better understanding of this now.

Comment: @sudobangbang that's not something i'd expect to run into on text files, but in that case you could probably read in the file and remove all the `\n` characters or something. Then you run into the problem of matching lines that end in `New York` and the next line says `Yankees`, but it was not the authors intent to record the team.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, agreed, I still second your original request for an example of the file to read

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import re

def world_series_count(team):
    with open("WorldSeriesWinners.txt") as f:
        data = f.read()
        items = re.findall(team, data)
    return len(items)

team = input('Enter a team name: ')

count = world_series_count(team)

print('{} won the world series {} times'.format(team, count))
```

Comment: regex seems a little unnecessary here.

Comment: Why not? I think it is good since we do not know the exact format of the names.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you people complicating matters way over necessary.

This will count occurrences of text in a txt file given by path, regardless of text formatting (unless it is hyphenized):

```
def count_in_file (path, text):
    f = open(path, "rb")
    c = f.read()
    f.close()
    return " ".join(c.split()).count(text.strip())
```

A little tweak will be needed to support unicode txt files. But there. Simple and easy.

If the txt file is extremely big, then perform this using buffering with static chunk size:

```
def count_in_file (path, text, chunksize=4096):
    text = text.strip()
    f = open(path, "rb")
    f.seek(0, 2)
    fsize = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    if fsize<=chunksize:
        c = f.read()
        f.close()
        return " ".join(c.split()).count(text)
    count = 0
    l = len(text)
    c = f.read(chunksize)
    r = c[-l:]
    while c:
        count += " ".join(c.split()).count(text)
        if r!=text: f.seek(f.tell()-l+1)
        c = f.read(chunksize)
        r = c[-l:]
    f.close()
    return count
```

Well, this now is a bit complicated. But if a file is really, really big, and it is formatted over lines, this is a good way to do it.