# Python - Fill an array from a file avoiding break line in the end

Tags: python, arrays

I was searching for how to define an empty array and fill it using a text file and got stuck at one point and couldn't find the solution.

My Script is :

```
array=[]
file=open("path\\file.txt","r")
array.append(file.readline())
array.append(file.readline()) #wanted to put only first 2 line just for learning.
incident_count=len(array)
print(incident_count)
print(array)
```

The first problem is that when I'm trying to put elements in array newline character is also attached("\n"). Also is append right function for putting elements in array.

Second when I'm trying to print the count of array It's printing number of char.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file.readline()[:-1]` this will return all the line except the last character which is `\n`

```
array.append(file.readline()[:-1])
array.append(file.readline()[:-1])
```

You can add `[:-1]` to avoid the last character which is `\n` consider this example :

```
hello\n
world\n
```

so when you read your file line by line the `\n` is include in each line, so to avoid `\n` you can read the line from index 0 to index `-1`

```
hello\n
^   ^_______index 4 or -1
|___________index 0
```

to understand more, take a look at this :

- [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

---

```
2
['hello', 'world']
```

Or like [Omar Einea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960118/define-an-empty-array-and-fill-from-file-in-python#comment84926799_48960171) mention in his comment you can use :

```
array.append(file.readline().rstrip())
array.append(file.readline().rstrip())
```

In case the last line not have a `\n`

Comment: I would go for `.rstrip()` to avoid removing the last character of the last line (in case last line doesn't have `\n`)

Comment: .rstrip() working as charm.......thnx again.Just a last question the append function I'm using to add elements to array is it the right way to add...?

Comment: @ronaldo take a look at my edit how my explanation can help you

Comment: @YCF_L thnx  man for explaining in such detail......Appreciate it!. can i ask you a last question...?  if we are reading hello so it will be from index 0 that is h   to index 4 o correct. so how we can put index -1 that is in reverse....

Comment: @ronaldo take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation you will understand better ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use: [str.splitlines() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

You'll end up with something like this:

```
array.append(file.readline().splitlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to append lines from file to list it always comes with "\n" so to avoid this we need to split the content.

Solution 1:

**array=[ ]

with open(r`C:\Users\wasim akram\Desktop\was.txt`) as fp:

    array = fp.read().splitlines()

print(array)**

Solution 2 :

**myNames=[ ]

f = open(r"C:\Users\wasim akram\Desktop\was.txt",'r')

for line in f:

    myNames.append(line.strip())

print(myNames)**

Comment: thnx for the help.....could you pls tell me is line a reserved keyword (does it have some specific function) or we can write anything here.

Comment: The code samples provided need to be indented to work, since python uses spaces to denote blocks of code.

Comment: @ronaldo "line" as in the sample above is just a variable.

Comment: @phil could you please tell me why we are using a variable and how it's getting just a single line at a time.cause in the above line we are reading the whole text file at once.

Comment: @ronaldo check out this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949508/python-read-all-text-file-lines-in-loop

Comment: @ronaldo In python if you iterate then line (just variable) will be list of all lines present in a file. You can change line to some other name also it will work

Comment: @Phil thnx for the post.I read the post and checked on internet also but pls can you help for clearing my doubt as I'm still getting that if we have to read line by line we use readline() function but here we have only opened the file and in the for loop also not used any function to get a single line only have used the strip function to get rid od whitelines.So, how a single line is getting fetch instead of whole file

Comment: @waseem akram shaik  ohhhh thnx a lot now I'm getting it.

Comment: @ronaldo readline() is not the only way to read lines.  The loop construct is iterating over a thing which is iterable.