# Best way to read and parse log file from AWS s3 using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, boto3

From Sagemaker

log file is read like follows:

```
sess = boto3.Session(region_name)
s3client = sess.client("S3")
log_obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=log_file_path)
log_obj["Body"].read()
```

which looks like this:

```
b'hello world this is log file1 \n arguments passed to function are \n [a,b,c,d] \n and so on...'
```

It is in one large text, unlike logs I see from other SO questions...

If \n writes next string into new line it would be much more easy to read, is there a way to let python NOT ignore escape character?

Or if there is better way to parse log of text from S3, let me know.

Comment: Try `log_obj["Body"].read().decode()`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Have you tried it with a `for` loop: [Python: read all text file lines in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949545/174777)

Comment: How do you know it does not respect `\n`? In your code you are not using `log_obj["Body"].read()` at all. What do you do with it? Save to a file? Print onto a console?

Comment: @Marcin there is log_obj["Body"].read(), last line. I'm trying to read it in sagemaker since simply downloading it from s3 has broken letters when opened.